# Pagination at server side (Java) while fetching the record from Azure Blob Storage

Tags: java, spring-boot, azure, azure-blob-storage

Hope you are doing well.
I am stuck in azure Blob Storage. I have container name "data" inside data there are 6000 files, now I have to fetch first 200 records on first query and then next 200 records on next query and so on (I am querying the data based on Tags).
So How can I add pagination from spring boot application?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to implement the Pagination on the Spring Boot Application then you need to change your Rest end points to include the page number and size details. Then create a pagable to object to send the pagable object to your repository.

**Sample Code:**

```
@GetMapping("/list")
    @ResponseBody
    public Page<Employee> Pagination(@RequestParam(defaultValue="0") int page, RequestParam(defaultValue = "30") int size) {
        Pageable paging = PageRequest.of(page, size);
        return employeeRepository.findAll(paging);
 }
```

You can find more details about pagination in the following links:

```
https://springframework.guru/spring-boot-pagination/ 
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-pagination-sorting
https://springframework.guru/spring-boot-pagination/
```